How to reference .this from within an instance of react interface?
I'm using a primereact component, whose props include a function, and I want to use one of the other props in this function. The overall scheme of things looks like this:
interface Props {
    label?: string;
    url?: string;
    style?: string;
    action?: (a: FuncArguments): void;
    [key: string]: any;
}

The thing I want to do is this:
const myItem : Props {
    label: "AwesomeName",
    style: myStyles.ordinaryItem,
    action: () => {
        someResolver.resolveSomething(this.label);
    }
};

Well... this.label is not accessible, because this is somehow always undefined and cannot even be cast to Props.
I'm not too much of a React wiz, or even a JS wiz, so this entire situation is making me a little confused.

You are using arrow function, which does not have access to the this context

I think the value you want is 'myItem.label', so to make your example work, you'd write:
const myItem: Props = {
    label: "AwesomeName",
    style: myStyles.ordinaryItem,
    action: function() {
        someResolver.resolveSomething(myItem.label);
}


You are using arrow function, using this in an arrow function only provide you properties  within the scope of the arrow function. You can either pass a label to the function or use a regular function
interface Props {
    label?: string;
    url?: string;
    style?: string;
    action?: (args: FuncArguments) => void;
    [key: string]: any;
}

const someResolver = {
    resolveSomething: (label: string) => {
         console.log("The resolved label: ", label);
    }
};
const myItem : Props {
    label: "AwesomeName",
    style: myStyles.ordinaryItem,
    action: function () {
        someResolver.resolveSomething(this.label);
       
    }
};

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrow_function.asp
